# Best way to parse string in perl

Tags: perl

To achieve below task I have written below C like perl program (As I am new to Perl), But I am not sure if this is the best way to achieve.

Can someone please guide? 
Note: Not with the full program, But where I can make improvement.

Thanks in advance

Input :

```
$str = "mail1, local<mail1@mail.local>, mail2@mail.local, <mail3@mail.local>, mail4 local<mail4@mail.local>"
```

Expected Output :

```
mail1, local<mail1@mail.local>
mail2@mail.local
<mail3@mail.local>
mail4, local<mail4@mail.local>
```

Sample Program

```
my $str="mail1, \@local<mail1\@mail.local>, mail2\@mail.local, <mail3\@mail.local>, mail4, local<mail4\@mail.local>";
my $count=0, @array, $flag=0, $tempStr="";
for my $c (split (//,$str)) {
    if( ($count eq 0) and ($c eq ' ') ) {
        next;
    }
    if($c) {
        if( ($c eq ',') and ($flag eq 1) ) {
            push @array, $tempStr;
            $count=0;
            $flag1=0;
            $tempStr="";
            next;
        }
        if( ($c eq '>' ) or ( $c eq '@' ) ) {
            $flag=1;
        }
        $tempStr="$tempStr$c";
        $count++;
    }
}
if($count>0) {
    push @array, $tempStr;
}
foreach my $var (@array) {
    print "$var\n";
}
```

**Edit:**

Input:

```
Input is the output of above code.
```

Expected Output :

```
"mail1, local"<mail1@mail.local>
"mail4, local"<mail4@mail.local>
```

Sample Code:

```
$str =~ s/([^@>]+[@>][^,]+),\s*/$1\n/g;
my @addresses = split('\n',$str);
if(scalar @addresses) {
    foreach my $address (@addresses) {
        if (($address =~ /</) and ($address !~ /\"/) and ($address !~ /^</)){
            $address="\"$address";
            $address=~ s/</\"</g;
        }
    }
    $str = join(',',@addresses);
}
print "$str\n";
```

Comment: Hang on, in this edit quotation (`"`) appeared, which doesn't seem right? (Please edit to correct if it shouldn't be there)

Comment: Done, Can you please help in solving edited question ?

Comment: Does the edit mean that you only want to keep those with description before `<...>` (so drop the others altogether), or that you want that description quoted when it's there (but otherwise keep all four records)?

Comment: Second half of your comment, 
I need that description(part before '<') quoted when it is there

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, you want to replace each:

- comma and following spaces,
- occurring after either `@` or `>`,

with a newline.

To make such replacement, instead of writing a parsing program, you can use
a regex.

The search part can be as follows:

```
([^@>]+[@>][^,]+),\s*
```

Details:

- `(` - Start of the 1st capturing group.

  - `[^@>]+` - A non-empty sequence of chars other than `@` or `>`.
  - `[@>]` - Either `@` or `>`.
  - `[^,]+` - A non-empty sequence of chars other than a comma.
- `)` - End of the 1st capturing group.
- `,\s*` - A comma and optional sequence of spaces.

The replace part should be:

- `$1` - The 1st capturing group.
- `\n` - A newline.

So the whole program, much shorter than yours, can be as follows:

```
my $str='mail1, local<mail1@mail.local>, mail2@mail.local, <mail3@mail.local>, mail4, local<mail4@mail.local>';
print "Before:\n$str\n";
$str =~ s/([^@>]+[@>][^,]+),\s*/$1\n/g;
print "After:\n$str\n";
```

To replace **all** needed commas I used `g` option.

Note that I put the source string in **single** quotes, otherwise Perl
would have complained about *Possible unintended interpolation of @mail*.

### Edit

Your modified requirements must be handled different way.
"Ordinary" replacement is not an option, because now there are some
fragments to **match** and some framents to **ignore**.

So the basic idea is to write a `while` loop with a **matching** regex:
`(\w+),?\s+(\w+)(<[^>]+>)`, meaning:

- `(\w+)` - First capturing group - a sequence of word chars (e.g. `mail1`).
- `,?\s+` - Optional comma and a sequence of spaces.
- `(\w+)` - Second capturing group - a sequence of word chars (e.g. `local`).
- `(<[^>]+>)` - Third capturing group - a sequence of chars other than `>`
  (actual mail address), enclosed in angle brackets, e.g. `<mail1@mail.local>`.

Within each execution of the loop you have access to the groups
captured in this particular match (`$1`, `$2`, ...).

So the content of this loop is to print all these captured groups,
with required additional chars.

The code (again much shorter than yours) should look like below:

```
my $str = 'mail1, local<mail1@mail.local>, mail2@mail.local, <mail3@mail.local>, mail4 local<mail4@mail.local>';
while ($str =~ /(\w+),?\s+(\w+)(<[^>]+>)/g) {
  print "\"$1, $2\"$3\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question(Even expected output also I edited). Is it ok if you can provide your feedback for that code change? Is there any better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), which in this case also needs a careful regex

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $string =   # broken into two parts for readabililty
    q(mail1, local<mail1@mail.local>, mail2@mail.local, )
 .  q(<mail3@mail.local>, mail4, local<mail4@mail.local>);

my @addresses = split /@.+?\K,\s*/, $string;

say for @addresses;
```

The `split` takes a full regex in its delimiter specification.  In this case I figure that each record is delimited by a comma which comes after the email address, so `@.+?,`

To match a pattern only when it is preceded by another brings to mind a [negative lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) before the comma. But those can't be of variable length, which is precisely the case here.

We can instead normally match the pattern `@.+?` and then use the [`\K` form](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.4/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) (of the lookbehind) which drops all previous matches so that they are not taken out of the string. Thus the above splits on `,\s*` when that is preceded by the email address, `@...` (what isn't consumed).

It prints

```
mail1, local<mail1@mail.local>
mail2@mail.local
<mail3@mail.local>
mail4, local<mail4@mail.local>
```

---

The edit asks about quoting the description preceding `<...>` when it's there. A simple way is to make another pass once addresses have been parsed out of the string as above. For example

```
my @addresses = split /@.+?\K,\s*/, $string;   #/ stop syntax highlight

s/(.+?,\s*.+?)</"$1"</  for @addresses;

say for @addresses;
```

The regex in a loop is one way to change elements of an array.  I use it for its efficiency (changes elements in place), conciseness, and as a demonstration of the following properties.

In a [foreach loop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) the index variable (or `$_`) *is an alias for the currently processed element* – so changing it changes that element.  This is a known source of bugs when allowed unknowingly, which was another reason to show it in the above form.

The statement also uses the [statement modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) and it is equivalent to

```
foreach my $elem (@addresses) {
    $elem =~ s/(.+?,\s*.+?)</"$1"</;
}
```

This is often considered a more proper way to write it but I find that the other form emphasizes more clearly that elements are being changed, when that is the sole purpose of the `foreach`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, Can you please help me with the edited question?